# sharepoint lookup field how to programmatically filter to lookup only in current document library

Tags: sharepoint, filtered-lookup

I want the lookup field to be filtered to only display titles from the current document library (meaning the document library that the user is currently in).  I cannot specify the document library b/c I don't want to have to define a new lookup column for each new document library...instead I'm hoping to do this as a custom content type that can be used in any document library.

It would ideally be deployed as a feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms446361.aspx">SharePoint Custom Fields.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms446361.aspx

Comment: Yes, I've looked into Custom Fields, but haven't seen any examples of what I'm trying to do.  I was hoping someone might know specifically how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of feature does not exist on SharePoint OTB.

Take look at this thread: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/sharepointadmin/thread/722EE26B-EC33-4618-8041-FAA92E149DE8. It provides some solutions though.